# Use en0 address as host in Django database setting

Tags: django, docker-compose, psql

I am trying to use my localhost database inside docker Django container.
I have allowed listen_address to all in postgresql.conf file.
I have added `host     all     all     localhost,192.168.1.9   trust` in pg_hba.conf file.

*192.168.1.9* is my en0 address. 
Now i want to use *192.168.1.9* as my host in database setting in django.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.9',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I am trying this but i am not able to succeed.
Am i doing something wrong? I want postgres to accept all connect so Django app container can connect to my local machine database. 
I am trying

```
psql -h 192.168.1.9 -U db_user -d db_name

Getting psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running on host "192.168.1.9" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I am not sure what wrong i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

the docker containers are usually on separate network interface (docker0), so if your app wants to access your host you have to use the docker0 interface.

you can get the ip of host from your container with

```
/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
```

Comment: Sorry i haven't got your point. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: docker creates new network interface in most cases, and uses 172.17.0.1 as the host Ip address (in most cases), so you have to use this IP address.... or try `docker inspect containername` and it will tell you more detail